# Android ORM which supports sync to a cloud and database cursor interfaces

Tags: android, orm, cursor, cloud, synchronization

Is there an Android ORM library which exposes database cursor interface (as to work with adapters etc.) AND supports cloud sync (to any cloud service)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have been using an ORM solution for years that works VERY well in Adapters and use Cursors.  We typically use the ORM tool to create a Cursor for the results, then do the following to pull the data from the Cursor:

```
Individual individual = new Individual(cursor);
name = individual.getName();
age = individual.getAge();
... etc ...

or

String name = Individual.getName(cursor);
int age = Individual.getAge(cursor);
```

The tool that we use (I'm an author) is DBTools (https://github.com/jeffdcamp/dbtools-android).